# Как изменить порядок выдачи при поиске в PHPShop?

Tags: php

Как изменить порядок выдачи при поиске в PHPShop ? Перерыл всё но никак не пойму в каком файле это настраивается

Answer (score -1):

В файле `query_filter.php`, в 124 строке, в запрос добавить `Order by id`.